# find where column could have multiple values, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to search where one column could equal one value and the other could have multiple values...

This works, with one value for each...

```
<%= Post.where("category LIKE ? OR commentary LIKE?", 20, "%mom%").count %>
```

This does not work...

```
<%= Post.where("category LIKE ? OR commentary LIKE?", 20, [{"%mom%", "%mother%"}]).count %>
```

How would be the best way to solve this in rails?

Thank you.

Comment: What does 20 represent

Comment: Seems the only possible way is `<%= Post.where("category LIKE ? OR commentary LIKE ? OR commentary LIKE ? ", 20, "%mom%", "%mother%").count %>`

Comment: that seems really inefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is only work with `IN`

You can do as follow;

```
<%= Post.where("category LIKE ? OR commentary LIKE? OR commentary LIKE?", 20, "%mom%", "%mother%"]).count %>
```

This will generate the following sql query;

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE (category like "20" OR commentary like "%mom%" OR commentary like "%mother%" )
```

Comment: is there any way to do it without repeating commentary?  i.e. if I had "mom", "mother", "mommy", "madre" etc...

Answer (score 2):

You could add it as a scope to move the repetition to your `Post` class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :categories_like, ->(to_match) { 
    where(
      [to_match.map("category like ?").join(" OR ")] + 
      (to_match.map { |m| "%#{m}%" })}
```

The scope adds as many `category like ?` clauses as there are categories to match and then adds each thing you want to match with `%` prefixed and suffixed. More details on adding scopes like there can be found in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). (I haven't tested the code as I'm not on my dev machine so it might need a little nudge in the right direction).

You can then use it like:

```
Post.categories_like(['mom', 'mother', 'madre']).count
```

As you've pointed out elsewhere it isn't the most efficient code in the whole world but then what you're asking it to isn't particularly efficient in SQL terms either.

Comment: thank you.  will use if I have to search a number of categories like this in the future.  giving you an up vote and muhamamd the check.