# Rails automatic scope based on params

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to improve a scope in a rails model, and I can't find how I can do that.

Right now i have a scope like that :

`scope :starts_with, -> (letters) { where("name like ?", "#{letters}%")}`

So I can do that :  `Wanker::State.starts_with('a')` and I get all states who starts with the letter *a*.

But I want do something like that :

`Wanker::State.starts_with(['a', 'b', 'c'])`

What will be the right scope for that ?

Comment: What DB you are using?

Comment: I saw a solution in stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956913/find-where-column-could-have-multiple-values-rails (second answer) but didn't work

Comment: Try `scope :starts_with, -> (letters) { where("name like ?", "(#{letters.join('|')})%")}`..

Comment: This operator `|` doesn't exist in Mysql LIKE constraint

Comment: But I see it is - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s08.html

Comment: I found ! `scope :starts_with, -> (letters) { where("name REGEXP ?", "^(#{letters.join('|')})")}`

Comment: yes.. by mistake I copied it as `like` instead of `REGEXP`.. Sorry

Comment: You might ask your self what is the size and volatility of the data? If it's small (say U. S. States). I'd read it once from the DB into memory and just operate on it with Ruby.  This is bad for high churn data or big data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
scope :starts_with, -> (letters) { where("name REGEXP ?", "^(#{letters.join('|')})")}
# or
scope :starts_with, -> (letters) { where("name RLIKE ?", "^(#{letters.join('|')})")}
```

> `p1|p2|p3` - *Alternation*; matches any of the patterns p1, p2, or p3

Check the  documentation of [`expr REGEXP pat, expr RLIKE pat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

> Performs a pattern match of a string expression expr against a pattern pat. The pattern can be an extended regular expression, the syntax for which is discussed later in this section. Returns 1 if expr matches pat; otherwise it returns 0. If either expr or pat is `NULL`, the result is `NULL`. `RLIKE` is a synonym for `REGEXP`, provided for mSQL compatibility.